# Android Swipe View?

Tags: android, layout, scroll, swipe, chomp

I don't know if you guys have ever heard of the app chomp but there is a layout in the app which looks like the image below. I'm wondering how they set this up what would i go about using to make something similar for my own application. The interesting part is when you swipe there is no scroll bar like a horizontal scroll view would have and the different things like snap into place. Just wondering what i should use to get this same effect thank you for any help

[image: https://g1.gstatic.com/android/market/com.chomp.android/ss-480-1-9]

Comment: chomp uses this component: http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-swipeview/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewPager, perhaps?

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

That will give you an effect similar to swiping between views in Android Market. I'm assuming that's the effect that you're describing?

Comment: it's different then that though i mean same snapping affect but not the same thing with the tabs at the top and what not

Comment: The new market uses it as well for screen shots in the apps description

Comment: ended up using viewpager for my app looks nicer imo anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

A SwipeView is an Android UI view similar to the homescreens.  You have several similar panes of content that you access by swiping left and right.  As you swipe left and right, transitions between the views are animated so that the view in focus follows your finger
http://droidweb.com/2011/03/implement-a-swipeview-in-android/